# Uninstalling Simplenote

Tags: uninstall

I recently downloaded the .deb package for simplenote, but when I tried to remove it, it doesn't show up in the Software Center. How do I remove Simplenote completely from my system?

Comment: Did you actually install it? You only state that you downloaded a DEB file, nothing about installing the DEB.

Comment: yes I installed it. sorry for not being clear

Comment: i downloaded the .deb package from the github and double clicked on it and then 'ubuntu software' app shows up and i clicked on the 'install' button.

Comment: Please post the output of `apt search simplenote`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need the package name. It is probably `simplenote`, but because I don't know, here is a way to get it:

`grep simplenote /var/log/dpkg.log`

An example line would be: `2014-01-02 11:20:08 status installed libmime-lite-perl 3.020-2ubuntu2` (`libmime-lite-perl` is the important part AKA package name)

Then, you can uninstall it:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge [packagename]`

Comment: If you know what the package name is for sure (it is probably not the `.deb` filename), you can skip the first bit.

Comment: The grep on dpkg.log is useful. Thanks for sharing.